# How to create a watchdog script to pause and continue processes in case other cpu-heavy processes are running?

Tags: shell-script, python, python3

I have a very large test setup which runs for several days on a server used by many parties in my university.

I would like to pause the process by pid (as well as processes executed by the process (in case there are currently processes running) and continue whenever the cpu-heavy processes are stopped. I would consider a cpu-heavy process as relevant when it uses at least one core at 100% for more than 15 seconds.

(I am not really sure how to interpret the "top" output but often there appear processes with 2300% cpu usage which I interpret as 23 cores are running at 100% or 22 at (100%-x%)*22=2300% etc.)

To pause a process there are basically two bash commands between which I have to choose:

```
kill -TSTP [pid]
```

and

```
kill -STOP [pid]
```

to continue the process I would use:

```
kill -CONT [pid]
```

Since my **python script** executed in the test setup does **runtime measurements of processes executed by it** I would like to ask whether there is a way to **measure only the time while the process is running**? (I also measure the exact computation time by a build-in function of the process executed by my python script but due to some questionable results (absolute time is questionable, the relative time seems to be correct) I also would have a less precise but at least somewhat usable time measurement from the outside (the python script))

**Summary**

1. How could I design a script that finds those processes and reacts
   accordingly? (No root on the server but I am allowed to see all
   processes executed and to handle my own processes)
2. How to do accurate time measurements (+/- 10 seconds) on those processes not including the time the process was paused?

Comment: It's better to use cgroups for prioritizing tasks.

Comment: But I am a normal user (and on this server even a guest) and I have to use the server because of certain software licenses. So I am pretty sure the admin won't put all the other users as well as me into cgroups with limited resources.